# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{x^n+y^n}$ for $x,y>1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Is there an analytical expression for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{x^n+y^n}$ when $x,y>1$? If so, how do you solve it?

Comment: Don't have a general approach, but you can certainly solve some boundary cases, like $y=0$ or $y=x$. What happens at $y=1$ and $y=2$?